# 4.6.10 upgrade from 4.2: Mailings component is broken; angular.js errors

Tags: mailing

[image: screenshot from a New Mailing page]

We've upgraded 4.2 LTS to the latest CiviCRM 4.6.10
New AJAX (angular.js) driven interface fails. Cache clean-up, template_c reset, disabling JS optimizer, removing custom tmpl and custom php did NOT affect the issue. Please, advise

Comment: Disable extensions. Question: is this a new Mailing or one that existed in the 4.2? If it existed, can you create a new one?

Comment: Have you tried going through the [javascript troubleshooting steps](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35850.0)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried the troubleshooting steps. The interface was broken regardless of the mailing.

Comment: The solution was to enforce the legacy mode via civicrm.settings.php:

define('CIVICRM_CIVIMAIL_UI_LEGACY', 1);

another website of ours with Joomla 2.5 + CiviCRM 4.6.10 exhibits the same exact behavior. It's clearly a compatibility issues with J2.5... and our customers would have to upgrade Joomla.